# my reports (pdf and excel) sometimes are empty

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

i have a procedure executed in form to generate data as excel or pdf ,anyway my problem is that sometimes my reports comes with no data and in another time it shows the data .

any suggestions please!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve].  Nobody here can help you with this without more concrete data.

Comment: Add more info about what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

If you used same parameters every time, then tables' contents is changing between two runs of that procedure. How? Someone updated something or deleted rows or broke foreign key constraints. Because, I don't see a reason why would e.g.

```
select * from emp
where deptno = 10
```

produce result "now" and 5 minutes later cause no data to be displayed.

If you think that this is not the case, provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the report/excel from a parameter form then there is a chance that there is not data in your database related to those parameters and that's why the excel and pdf are empty.

and if that's not the case then briefly tell your running method of the reports. 
regards: hassan